# Illustrator - paint/draw inside the drawing created from brush strokes, not shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, brush, drawing, clipping-mask

I have been struggling with this for last few days and decided to get expert help here. I have drawing like below (original art is more complex) which was created using brush strokes (no built-in shape objects). I am trying to paint/draw inside using brush strokes just like "draw inside" feature of Illustrator. As it works for closed shapes so I thought making sure all lines are connected will suffice, but it didn't.

As a test, when I tried using Shape builder tool to color, it works perfectly as it treats inside square as a closed shape but I don't want fill colors so this wont work, I want to color using my textured brushes.

I have also tried coloring the background in another layer and using this drawing as clipping mask by Object>Compound Path>Make but it didn't help either. I am new to clipping mask so not sure if there is another way.

[image]

So the simple question is how can I restrict painting inside the following drawing?
[image]

Thanks for help!

Edit: Billy's answer is perfect and I was able to do this quickly as a test. I can paint in multiple shapes like face, body, hair now. Just created a duplicate layer of drawing to keep my lines still there.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one method

1. Select the black lines you drew
2. Do *Object > Expand Appearance*
3. Select the Shape Builder tool, and click in the centre, to make the inside a closed shape
4. Do *Ungroup* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
5. Select the closed shape you made
6. Set the fill and stroke of this shape to none
7. Select the brush tool, and select the *Draw Inside* mode

Example

[image]

Comment: Wow. Can't express my gratitude. I thought it wasn't possible in AI and was going to give up. Thanks a lot Billy.